# GDPR Information and consent

Tags: gdpr, consent

I am building a game that stores score/level on the local device and uses non-personalized AdMob.

Do I need to inform the user about storing the score locally?

Do I need consent for using non-personal AdMob?

Do I need to ask for the age? How should I handle kids?

Can I disallow a user from using the app if consent is not given?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to inform the user about storing the score locally?

No, there is no need as long as you don't transmit, store or process any personal info. It's doubtful that the score could be considered personal info, but you're not sending it to your servers in any way, so you don't seem to be processing it anyway.

> Do I need consent for using non-personal AdMob?

You have to check this with AdMob, but usually, if it is non-personal, they shouldn't be processing any PI, so you're clear without informing.

> Do I need to ask for the age? How should I handle kids?

Again, you're not processing any PI, so regarding GDPR there isn't any problem.

> Can I disallow a user from using the app if consent is not given?

If you needed consent, no, it would be unlawful to block a user for not giving consent, unless it is impossible to provide the service without it. See recital 43:

> Consent is presumed not to be freely given if [...] the performance of a contract, including the provision of a service, is dependent on the consent despite such consent not being necessary for such performance.

Comment: If the app is living from ads, how can I exclude users that don’t wish to see ads?

Comment: The GDPR doesn't provide for users opting out of ads, only of the ads being targeted using PI. If a user doesn't give consent, he gets the same amount of ads, but not targeted.

Comment: [Google suggests that AdMob always requires the user's consent.](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7676680) Non-personalized ads might not target ads using personal data, but still access data on the device in order to prevent ad fraud. While the GDPR might not require consent here, ePrivacy does.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to inform the user about storing the score locally.

You don't need consent for using non-personal AdMob ads.

You don't have to ask for age unless the law requires: this is usually when your app displays sexual content

You can state in the user agreement that the user is not allowed to use your app if they do x, but unless you have a way from physically stopping them from using the app (e.g sign in system) that clause in the agreement won't do anything.

Comment: If consent is required then the age becomes important, because children cannot consent (compare GDPR Art 8, which sets a minimum age of 13 to 16 years for consent, depending on member state laws).